# c# asp.net click button to "save as", but downloaded file becomes unintentionally modified

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a method in my C# codebehind that connects to SQL and creates a CSV file based upon the SQL data. This method is called when the user clicks a particular button on the website. I am trying to get this same method to also prompt the user to "open" or "save as" after the CSV file is generated.

I have tried the following:

```
System.Web.HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "C:\\temp\\report.csv" + ";");           
Response.TransmitFile("C:\\temp\\report.csv");
```

The user does get prompted to "open or save as". In either case, the data in the CSV file also contains the entire source code of my Default.aspx. What do I need to do to my code to prevent that extra data from being appended onto my CSV? TIA...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `response.End()` to prevent further processing by your page.

Answer (score 1):

You need to clear the Response first - `Response.Clear();`

```
response.Clear();
...
response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "C:\\temp\\report.csv" + ";");           
Response.TransmitFile("C:\\temp\\report.csv");
```